# Sorting dates with months or days on 0

Tags: php, sorting, date, datetime

I have to sort some dates on PHP, in which some of them can have '0' on the month or day, for example:

1951-11-00

1951-12-14

Problem is that this dates don't get sorted with other dates that have all the year, day and month values.

First I tried using array_multisort:

```
    foreach ($Objects as $key => $part) {
        $sort[$key] = strtotime($part['Object']['date']);
    }
    array_multisort($sort, SORT_DESC, $Objects );
```

It sort it ok, but it first sorts the values that have 00 on the month or day, and then it sort the normal dates, for example:

1937-05-00

1937-04-00

1935-11-00

1951-12-16

1951-12-14

As you see, the order is not ok, because the dates with 1951 should go first, but the sort algorithm is classifying the dates in two groups, the ones that have 00, and the ones that have the full numbers.

Then I tried uasort, but I'm not getting good results.

How can I sort this dates correctly? For the list that I put, I need it to show on this order (regardless of having the month on 00):

1951-12-16

1951-12-14

1937-05-00

1937-04-00

1935-11-00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just sort them as strings. They are already in a comparable format when compared as strings.

```
$dates = [
    '1937-05-00',
    '1937-04-00',
    '1935-11-00',
    '1951-12-16',
    '1951-12-14'
];

usort($dates, function($a, $b) {
    return $a < $b;
});

var_export($dates);
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/444218)